# Delete rows in a matrix using another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have two matrices `A` and `B`:

```
A <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=2, 1:10)
#        [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    6
# [2,]    2    7
# [3,]    3    8
# [4,]    4    9
# [5,]    5   10

B <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2, c(2,1,7,6))
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    2    7
#  [2,]    1    6
```

I want to get a matrix `C` which has the rows of `A` which are not present in `B`. So `C` should be:

```
#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    8
# [2,]    4    9
# [3,]    5   10
```

Is there a quick way (i.e. without using loops) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
 A[!(A[,1] %in% B[,1] & A[,2] %in% B[,2]),]
#       [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    8
#[2,]    4    9
#[3,]    5   10
```

Consider, if

```
B[4] <- 5
A[!(A[,1] %in% B[,1] & A[,2] %in% B[,2]),]
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]    3    8
#[3,]    4    9
#[4,]    5   10
```

Also, you can

```
 A[!(apply(A, 1, paste, collapse="") %in% apply(B, 1, paste, collapse="")),]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `setdiff` or `%in%`

```
matrix(setdiff(A,B),ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    8
#[2,]    4    9
#[3,]    5   10
```

**OR**

```
matrix(A[!A %in% B],ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    8
#[2,]    4    9
#[3,]    5   10
```